# Label and value display

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm using a simple code that displays the square root of a number in a label, but for some reason the values get overlaped in a way that I couldn't avoid it, which means that, if I use it for a number that has a exact square root, then the answer goes messed up with the previous answer of many digits.

I've been use the next code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *

def square_calc():
    x = x_val.get()
    sqx = x ** 0.5
    print x, "** 0.5 =", sqx
    sqx_txt = Label(root, text = "x ** 0.5 =").grid(row=3, column=0)
    sqx_lab = Label(root, text = sqx).grid(row=3, column=1)

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculating square root")

x_val = DoubleVar()

x_lab   = Label(root, text = "x").grid(row=0, column=0)
nmb     = Entry(root, textvariable = x_val).grid(row=0, column=1)
calc    = Button(root, text = "Calculate", command=square_calc).grid(columnspan=2)
y_lab   = Label(root, text = " ").grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to round a number?

Comment: Well, what I want is that the program deletes the previous answer instead of just overlapping the new answer.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove a label?

Comment: It could be, if there is no other way, then that's more likely to be the case, although , I don't know how to do that

Comment: You can remove a placed widget from the `grid` with `grid_forget()`, but what's really needed here is a simple `config()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display is getting messed-up because every time your `square_calc()` function is called it creates new pair of `Label`s, but this may leave some parts of any previous ones visible. Since the one on the left is the same every time, so it's not noticeable with it, but the text in one on the right in column 1 is potentially different every time.

A simple way to fix that is to make the `Label` a global variable and create it outside the function, and then just change its contents in the function. As with all Tkinter widgets, this is can be done after it's created by calling the existing obj's `config()` method.

Here's a minimally-modified version of your code that illustrates doing that. Note, it also adds a `sticky` keyword arugment to the `grid()` method call for the label to left-justify it within the grid cell so it's closer to the text label immediately to its left (otherwise it would be center-justified within the cell).

```
from Tkinter import *

def square_calc():
    x = x_val.get()
    sqx = x ** 0.5
#    print x, "** 0.5 =", sqx
    sqx_txt = Label(root, text = "x ** 0.5 =").grid(row=3, column=0)
    sqx_lab.config(text=sqx)
    sqx_lab.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculating square root")

x_val = DoubleVar()

x_lab   = Label(root, text = "x").grid(row=0, column=0)
nmb     = Entry(root, textvariable = x_val).grid(row=0, column=1)
calc    = Button(root, text = "Calculate", command=square_calc).grid(columnspan=2)
y_lab   = Label(root, text = " ").grid(row=3, column=0)
sqx_lab = Label(root, text = " ")

root.mainloop()
```

There's another potentially serious flaw in your code. All those assignments of the form

```
variable = Widget(...).grid(...)
```

result in assigning the value `None` to the variable because that's what the `grid()` method returns. I didn't fix them because they do no harm in this cause since none of those variables are ever referenced again, but it would have been a problem if the new globally variable `sqx_lab` had been done that way since it is referenced elsewhere.

Comment: An answer like this forces the reader to go line-by-line to look for differences. Your answer would be much better if you added a little bit of an explanation as to what the main problem was. For example, while switching to a class-based solution is good advice, it has  absolutely nothing to do with the problem, but a beginner won't likely know that.

Comment: @Bryan: Point taken, however now it's mostly redundant given the other answer.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the explanation given. I was trying the 'config' option, but I was getting : "Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user03\Desktop\Python\square_root_tk_fail.py", line 7, in square_calc
    sqx_lab["text"] = str(sqx)...
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment"; and this is what you mentioned also as a flaw in the code, anyway, I guess I need more experience before I figure out how to use classes.

Comment: You're welcome. Using Tkinter is difficult, since it's not well documented and somewhat quirky (in my opinion). Regardless, learning to use classes is very worthwhile objective (pun intended ;-), not just for dealing with Tkinter, but because the concepts can be used just about everywhere to improve the software you develop.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, every time you call `square_calc()`, you are simply creating and placing another `Label`. The right way to do this is to create a `Label` outside the function, then have the function update the `Label`'s text with `mylabel.config(text='new text')`.